# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61]に対応するためのポートの変更の方法を教えてください

Tags: python, python3, django

Mac, Python3, Django, PostgreSQLを利用して、ローカル環境でWEBアプリを開発しています。

開発しているDjangoのプログラムをローカルサーバー上で起動し動作を確認していると、以下のエラーが出ます。
Django allauthを利用してユーザー登録、ログイン関係のページを作成してから出るようになりました。

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61]
```

このエラーを手がかりに対策について調べると、ポート番号を変える事がひとつの対策になるという情報があったので試したいのですが、どのようにポートの設定を変更すれば良いかわかりません。
この方法についてご教授いただけないでしょうか？

参照した情報:
[Python ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814712/python-connectionrefusederror-errno-61-connection-refused)

現在のローカルのポートは以下のとおりです。

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

**実行環境**
Mac: mojave 10.14.6
Python: 3.7.5
Django: 2.2.2
PostgreSQL:12.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[こちらのサイト](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563227/django-allauth-example-errno-61-connection-refused)を参考にし、
settings.pyに、

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

を加える事でエラーが出なくなりました。